# Adding labels to pie chart in R... Radiating "spokes"?

Tags: r, charts, ggplot2, pie-chart

Is there a way (using ggplot or some other package maybe) to angle the labels of a pie chart in R? For example, this code (using R defaults):

```
data <- c(4,9,2,5)
names <- c("alpha","beta","gamma","delta")
pie(data,names)
```

Creates this pie chart:
[image]

What I want is a pie chart like this (which I created very roughly in PhotoShop):
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @agstudy pointed out, you need to modify the body of the function to create your own `pie` function. Indeed, `pie` does not return any value so you don't know where exactly to put your labels and with which angle.

First, you can get the body of `pie` with `graphics::pie`

At the end of the function, the pie is drawn with :

```
for (i in 1L:nx) {
    n <- max(2, floor(edges * dx[i]))
    P <- t2xy(seq.int(x[i], x[i + 1], length.out = n))
    polygon(c(P$x, 0), c(P$y, 0), density = density[i], angle = angle[i], 
        border = border[i], col = col[i], lty = lty[i])
    P <- t2xy(mean(x[i + 0:1]))
    lab <- as.character(labels[i])
    if (!is.na(lab) && nzchar(lab)) {
        lines(c(1, 1.05) * P$x, c(1, 1.05) * P$y)
        text(1.1 * P$x, 1.1 * P$y, labels[i], xpd = TRUE, 
             adj = ifelse(P$x < 0, 1, 0), ...)
    }
}
```

The part that is interesting to you is what follows `text`, where you can specify an angle to rotate them (like @agstudy did). In order to use the correct angle, you've got to compute it (this is the part where my answer becomes different from the other one...).
Actually, it is already computed right before the drawing, with:

```
t2xy <- function(t) {
    t2p <- twopi * t + init.angle * pi/180
    list(x = radius * cos(t2p), y = radius * sin(t2p))
}
```

you just need to make this function also output the angle:

```
t2xy <- function(t) {
    t2p <- twopi * t + init.angle * pi/180
    list(x = radius * cos(t2p), y = radius * sin(t2p), an=t2p)
}
```

Then, you can specify the parameter `srt` in the `text` call, putting the angle in degrees, with 2 options according to x:

```
text(1.1 * P$x, 1.1 * P$y, labels[i], xpd = TRUE, 
     srt = ifelse(P$x < 0, P$an/pi*180+180, P$an/pi*180),
     adj = ifelse(P$x < 0, 1, 0), ...)
```

With your data, calling the modified `pie` function, you'll get the below plot:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just add before calling the `pie`:

```
par(srt=45)
```

This will rotate any text in the plot.

Or better :

```
pie(data,names,srt=45)
```

#### give different rotations angles:

If you want to set many rotation angles, you need to hack the `pie` function:

1. Add an `srt` argument
2. Replace the line :

   ```
    text(1.1 * P$x, 1.1 * P$y, labels[i], xpd = TRUE, 
      adj = ifelse(P$x < 0, 1, 0),col='blue', ...)
   ```

   by

   ```
    text(1.1 * P$x, 1.1 * P$y, labels[i], xpd = TRUE, 
      adj = ifelse(P$x < 0, 1, 0),col='blue',srt=srt[i], ...)
   ```

Now you call the new function :

```
pie(data,names,srt=c(45,50,45,-12))
```

[image]