# Rotate text to center of circle (problem with specifying suitable angle)

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts

I have a problem with rotating text into the circle. Just like in [Adding labels to pie chart in R... Radiating "spokes"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30885116/adding-labels-to-pie-chart-in-r-radiating-spokes). I tried to make analogous thinking in my example but I don't quite understand solution.

Let's take my code following.[image]

```
rotate=function(vec){
  df<-data.frame(table(vec))
  colnames(df)[1]<-'group'
  angle_diff<-30
  #creating bar plot first
  bp<- ggplot(df, aes(x="", y=Freq, fill=group))+
    geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity")
  blank_theme <- theme_minimal()+
    theme(
      axis.title.x = element_blank(),
      axis.title.y = element_blank(),
      panel.border = element_blank(),
      panel.grid=element_blank(),
      axis.ticks = element_blank(),
      plot.title=element_text(size=14, face="bold")
    )
  #adding polar coordinates to make a circle
  pie <- bp + coord_polar("y", start=0)
  pie + scale_fill_brewer("Characteristic",palette='Dark2') + blank_theme +
    theme(axis.text.x=element_blank())+
    geom_text(aes(y = rev(Freq)/2 + c(0, cumsum(rev(Freq))[-length(Freq)]),
                  label = print(paste0(rev(Freq),'(',percent(rev(Freq)/(sum(Freq))),')')),angle=angle_diff), size=5)
  
}
rotate(c(rep(3,30),rep(4,40),rep(5,70),rep(6,60)))
```

As we can see pink part of pie chart is looking good, instead of others. I treid to fix proper angle which will work for all part of pies but I didn't manage that. Let's note that for orange part angle change should be very close to 0, and in green part it should be more than 180. Do have any ideas how this proper angle can be fixed ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are more likely to receive a useful answer if you can remove all the code that is unnecessary to illustrate the actual problem (like themes, scales, etc.).

Comment: Good remark! Thanks. I improved code by omitting things not connected with problem ;))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The calculation of the angle is a bit tricky. You need to calculate the center of each slice, which is the cumulative sum of frequencies minus half the width. Then rescale to 360 degrees (divide by the max and multiple by 360), and finally add 90 degrees to have the text going outwards (instead of perpendicular).

Ideally one could do this using the label positions calculated internally by `position_stack`, but I couldn't figure out how to use `after_stat` or `after_scale` to get that to work.

```
rotate <- function(vec){
  require(ggplot2)
  require(scales)
  
  df <- as.data.frame(table(vec))
  colnames(df)[1] <- 'group'
  df$label <- paste0(df$Freq,' (', percent(df$Freq / sum(df$Freq)),')')
  df$angle <- (cumsum(df$Freq) - 0.5 * df$Freq) / sum(df$Freq) * 360 + 90

  ggplot(df, aes(x = "", y = Freq, fill = group)) +
    geom_col(width = 1, show.legend = FALSE) +
    geom_text(
      aes(label = label, angle = angle), 
      position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), 
      size = 5
    ) +
    coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
    theme_void()
}
rotate(c(rep(3,30),rep(4,40),rep(5,70),rep(6,60)))
```

[image]

If you'd like the text to always be right-side up, we need to check whether the calculated angle is over 180 using a modulus. So change the angle calculation to:

```
df$angle <- ((cumsum(df$Freq) - 0.5 * df$Freq) / sum(df$Freq) * 360) %% 180 - 90
```

[image]